# unable to login as admin in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have multi-authentication set up in my laravel app. I am trying to create multiple authentication using default authentication laravel 5.8. I have two tables one is users and other is admins. I have configured the guards for admin. User login works fine, no issues but when I try to login the admin, it  doesn't work even if I login with correct credentials. Password field validation works if I use less then 6 character. Please help me to solve this problem.`enter code here`
    My Admin model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'title',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}


Guard setting is


'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],



    AdminLoginController is
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }
    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {

        //validate the form
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
        //attemp to login
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            //Authentication passed...
            return 'success';
            //return redirect()
            //->intended(route('admin.dashboardsdsdsd'));

            //if login success then redirect to page
            // if not success then redirect to back

        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

Route is

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');

Route::get('admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, so that admin can login.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons:

**First one**: your hash password is not correct, so open this [website](https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/?fbclid=IwAR3ZYud0E_M206otperCOiPIpiBMumtIafcsMId8JEiFEe1mjgTtA7qGaS8) ( which is MD5 Hash Generator) then put any number that you like, take it and create a new admin account directly from database and paste the password then try

**Second one**: Clear your cache and  view :

```
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan cache:clear
```